# RelativeLayout- android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" and android:layout_centerVertical="true" dont center the imageview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

For some strange reason  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`       and      `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` dont center the `ImageView` don't seem to center my `ImageView`

Any suggestions?

The image is stuck in the upper right left hand corner of the screen and it does not center as expected.

SOURCE:

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emblem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/start" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/go_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/apn_app_go_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/go_button"
            android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/start_text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>*
```

Comment: If you change the `LinearLayout` orientation to vertical, it will put it below the button automatically. You can use `layout_gravity` to center after that.

Comment: Your RelativeLayout that has the imageView is not positioned in the parent RelativeLayout where you want it.  It is only centering it in a  child layout that has not been positioned yet.  So the child layout is probably exactly the same size as the image. Try setting the RelativeLayout of the imageView to be centered in the parent.

Comment: Next time you get your original question fixed and want to ask a **completely different** question, just write a new question. An "edit" shouldn't completely change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `centerHorizontal` to the relative layout. Currently, you are centering the image in the image view (basically you are centering the image in the view), what you want is the relative layout to have the contents centered.

Try:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emblem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The other option is to do:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emblem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" //change to match_parent
            android:layout_height="match_parent" //change to match_parent
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/apn_app_logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The second option sets the width and height of the `imageView` to match the `relativeView`, which would allow you to use the `centerHorizontal` and `centerVertical` in the `imageView`

Comment: That would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use android:layout_below in a LinearLayout.  You could put these two items in a RelativeLayout, or you could change your LinearLayout from "horizontal" to "vertical" as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I updated my question a few seconds before you posted this... (I think you may want to update your answer)